# How to use yii2-user as sub-module inside another module

Tags: module, yii2

I want to implement one module in an existing application.In that module I am trying to use yii2-user module.The yii2 docs say we can do that.

```
namespace app\modules\forum;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->modules = [
            'admin' => [
                // you should consider using a shorter namespace here!
                'class' => 'app\modules\forum\modules\admin\Module',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

I have module code as

```
namespace app\modules\cdas;

class cdas extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\cdas\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // custom initialization code goes here
        $this->modules = [
           'user' => [
                'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
                 'modelMap' => [
                    'Profile' => 'app\modules\cdas\models\users\Profile',
                    'User'=>'aapp\modules\cdas\models\users\User',
                ],  
                'controllerMap' => [
                   'settings' => 'app\modules\cdas\controllers\user\SettingsController',
                   'admin' => 'app\modules\cdas\controllers\user\AdminController',
                   'role' => 'app\modules\cdas\controllers\user\RoleController',
                   'security' => 'app\modules\cdas\controllers\user\SecurityController',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

But when I use the above methodology and try to access

```
http://localhost/<app_name>/web/cdas/user/security/login
```

I get the following error

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object
in ....vendor\dektrium\yii2-user\views\_alert.php

/**
 * @var $module dektrium\user\Module
 */



<?php if ($module->enableFlashMessages): ?>
```

Please suggest proper way to implement the sub-module.

Comment: The question is, what line and what variable is the error about, that is information I don't see here. Your implementation seems correct at first glance.

Comment: @Blizz the line showing error is <?php if ($module->enableFlashMessages): ?>. Most probably its not getting the module instance.

Comment: Yeah I kinda suspected that but it seems so weird... it actually finds the modules, the views, but then it fails to pass an instance?